# Why is my JavaScript Function incorrect?

Tags: javascript

I am having difficulties with this function in JavaScript producing the outcome that I need. I am trying to find if the strings are the same length and this is what I have so far:

```
function areSameLength(str1, str2) {
    if (str1 === str2) {
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

I am not sure why this is not correct.

Comment: You need to compare _lengths_, not strings themselves. And no need to `return true/false` explicitly; just return result of comparing str1.length vs str2.length.

Comment: "_I am not sure why this is not correct._" Because you did nothing to check the length, you only compared if the strings are the same (as in they have the same sequence of characters). You need something like `str1.length == str2.length`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `"string".length` so it would be:

```
function areSameLength(str1, str2) {
    if (str1.length === str2.length) {
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

or more simply

```
function areSameLength(str1, str2) {
    return str1.length === str2.length;
}
```

BUT you can start to get more complicated than that.  If you wanted to make sure str1 or str2 is a string before checking:

```
function areSameLength(str1, str2) {
    if ((typeof str1 == 'string' || str1 instanceof String) && (typeof str2 == 'string' || str2 instanceof String)) {
        return str1.length === str2.length;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

What this does is check the type and instance of a variable to ensure it's a string. But it is kinda ugly.  So you would probably want to make that a function too.

```
function isString(str)
{
    return typeof str == 'string' || str instanceof String;
}

function areSameLength(str1, str2)
{
    if (isString(str1) && isString(str2))
    {
        return str1.length === str2.length;
    }
    // return false if anything else
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing two strings to see if they are equal, meaning only identical strings will match.

Use [the `length` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length) to check if they are the same length, but not necessarily the same characters:

```js
function areSameLength(str1, str2) {
    return str1.length === str2.length;
}


// Some tests to show it works:
console.log(areSameLength('', '')); // true
console.log(areSameLength('test', 'test')); // true
console.log(areSameLength('testing', 'abcdefg')); // true
console.log(areSameLength('a', 'bcd')); // false
```

Also, you don't need an if else statement here, since the comparison returns a boolean value, you can simply return that value.

Answer (score 1):

```
function areSameLength(str1, str2) {
    if (str1.length === str2.length) { // you want to compare the lengths, not the strings themselves
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

Better, shorter version:

```
function areSameLength(str1, str2) {
    return str1.length === str2.length;
}
```

Comment: That's an antipattern: don't do `if (condition) { return true } else { return false }`, just return the condition directly. I know OP has that but it's a change for improvement :)

Comment: Just want to note, the short version costs you ~75 characters and saves you all of 2 characters per call. If you're not doing higher-order function stuff, it's not worth the cost, neither in extra code nor in readability.

Comment: Thank you. I couldn't remember the correct to do compare length. Thank you all so much.

Comment: @JonathanReeves No problem. Then you can accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length) property of the strings.

> The `length` property of a [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) object indicates the length of a string, in UTF-16 code units.

```js
function areSameLength(str1, str2) {
    return str1.length === str2.length;
}

console.log(areSameLength('', ''));
console.log(areSameLength('', 'a'));
console.log(areSameLength('foo', 'bar'));
console.log(areSameLength('baz', ''));
```